# Duda en JS, no detecta una accion "click"

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda acerca de lo siguiente: Lo que pasa es que necesito detectar una acción click en JS, esto lo hago a través de su clase. Pero mi duda es la siguiente, hay alguna razón por la que no detecte esta acción si es creado por otra función de JS. Lo que quiero decir es que ahora creo elementos dependiendo de la cantidad de un select option lo que en JavaScript lo hago así:

```
function showTraffic(select) {
    var str = '';
    if (select.value == 0) {
        alert("Seleccione un numero válido");
    }else{

        for (var i = 0; i < select.value; i++) {
            str+='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10 "><div class="background"><div id="box-out"><div id="box-inside"><div><input id="circulo1" class="color1 tt" type="button" disabled name="verde" ></div><div><input id="circulo2" class="color2 tt" type="button" disabled name="amarillo"></div><div><input id="circulo3" class="color3 tt" type="button" disabled name="rojo"></div></div></div></div></div>'
            $('#semaforo').html(str);
        }
    }
}
```

eso funciona no hay problema, pero cuando quiero detectar cual elemento se le dio click no hace nada, sin embargo cuando lo pego en html sin hacer lo de "crear" con un select si lo reconoce y si funciona. El código que uso es este:

```
$("#circulo1").on('click',  function() {
    let id = this.id;
    var color = ['verde','amarillo', 'rojo'];
    if (id == "circulo1") {
        var dataString2 = color[0];
        var dataString = "encendido";
        var dataString1 = "semaforo1";
        $("#circulo1").addClass('encender');
        $("#circulo2").removeClass('encender');
        $("#circulo3").removeClass('encender');
    }else if(id == "circulo2"){
        var dataString2 = color[1];
        var dataString = "encendido";
        var dataString1 = "semaforo1";
        $("#circulo1").removeClass('encender');
        $("#circulo2").addClass('encender');
        $("#circulo3").removeClass('encender');
    }else if(id == "circulo3"){
        var dataString2 = color[2];
        var dataString = "encendido";
        var dataString1 = "semaforo1";
        $("#circulo1").removeClass('encender');
        $("#circulo2").removeClass('encender');
        $("#circulo3").addClass('encender');
    }
});
```

hay alguna razón por la que no funcione?

Comment: Entiendo que intentas acceder al select por class en tu comentario pero al ver tu código lo haces buscando por id. Para buscar por class en vez de '#' debes usar "." También quizás tu codigo de click se este cargando antes de tu metodo de creación de los select por ese motivo no te lo este encontrando. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para asociar eventos a elementos agregados dinámicamente, tenés que utilizar [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('click', '#circulo1', function () {
    ...
});
```

Como selector tenés que pasar algún elemento que esté presente al momento de asociar el evento.